# IIS Web API cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, sql-server-express

I have this website(Web API) that needed to be deployed locally.
[Screenshot of website from debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3qk3.png)

The website was connected to an SQL Server Express.
[Screenshot of Database Credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0MDp.png)

So I tried using IIS for the website but shows error on production
[Screenshot from production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdJyW.png)

What Ive Tried:

- Added `location allowOverride="true"`
- Allow Connection of port(8080 in my case) in firewall

My Connection String:

```
connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-68AOHFF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BFPData;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Is there anything I missed? I don't really have background on putting dynamic website on IIS, Thanks for Helping!

Edit:

found this [Test Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkRcD.png) I dont this effect my deployment

Comment: config error: cannot read config due insufficient permissions (from your screenshot)

Comment: @ssilas777 yeah I tried checking the web config but nothing seems to stand out

Comment: Following on from what ssilas777 said... if you want IIS to serve up content from a folder on your private Desktop then the IIS_IUSRS account needs at least Read permissions on the C:\Users\user\Desktop\webApp\ folder.